# How can I extract raw byte arrays stored in Map<?, byte[]> objects from a Java heap dump?

Tags: java, jvm, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have a Java application (Kafka Streams app) where a few `ConcurrentSkipListMap` objects are maintained (in InMemoryWindowStore). The type of the key of the maps is `org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Bytes` and the values are `byte[]`. The byte arrays are serialized Protocol Buffers objects.

I have taken a heap dump of this app for investigating an issue and I want to extract the byte arrays stored as the values of the maps, deserialize those byte arrays into Protocol Buffers objects and inspect them. Those maps contain 3 million mappings (based on what I see on Eclipse Memory Analyzer). Is there a good way to somehow extract those raw byte arrays in the maps in the heap dump?

Answer (score 1):

Select the byte array, then use Copy > Save Value to File.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for my usecase, because non-ascii parts get converted into `.`.

Comment: It should have worked for a single byte[] array, as the help says:

Save to a file the value of char[], String, StringBuffer or StringBuilder into a text file, or for a single primitive array store the elements as binary, or for other types, the printable value or the class name and address.

but perhaps there is a bug in https://git.eclipse.org/c/mat/org.eclipse.mat.git/tree/plugins/org.eclipse.mat.ui/src/org/eclipse/mat/ui/snapshot/actions/SaveValueAsQuery.java

Comment: Thank you pointing that out, actually it seems to work with just single entry (it doesn't convert them into `.`) but not for multiple entries (the `.` conversion kicks in in that case). Now the question is how do I do this for 3 million entries.